# Lost boot option 'debian' after switching between UEFI and Legacy

Tags: debian, grub, bios

In a stupid attempt to test something I switched between UEFI and Legacy on my Dell XPS13 where I am running Debian Bullseye on an encrypted SSD.

Sofar I have tried several things according to the most useful similar questions here, but I cannot recover the boot option 'debian'.
From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831216/how-can-i-reinstall-grub-to-the-efi-partition) I gathered most of the used options below, which are kind of similar to [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall).

```
# decrypt drive
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 mydisk

# mount
sudo mount /dev/mapper/ALF--vg-root /mnt
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done

sudo chroot /mnt

grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
update-grub

exit
```

The output of `efibootmgr -v` before (see below) only changes to `BootOrder: 0003,0007`, but somehow gets reset apparently when rebooting (Ive tried this several times)?

```
BootCurrent: 0007
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,13a9ec87-8ccb-4b03-9a6a-82ef130b8028,0x109000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...o................
Boot0003* debian        HD(1,GPT,d68c44b3-646d-4e6d-9c3f-16b2ff1fd834,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0007* UEFI: SanDisk U3 Cruzer Micro 8.02, Partition 1       PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x3b632446,0x800,0xb057ee)..BO
```

I dont now if this helps, but there are several efi-files, for some reason there are 2 nested uppercase `EFI` direcotries:

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ ls /mnt/boot/efi/EFI
Dell  EFI  debian
kubuntu@kubuntu:~$ ls /mnt/boot/efi/EFI/debian/
BOOTX64.CSV  fbx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
```

I am open to any hints and suggestions.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO (unless 21.10)
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I eventually gave in yesterday and used boot-repair and I somehow I managed to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Fixed it with a Boot-Repair USB and mounting root volume in initramfs to correct device name.

I eventually tried Boot-Repair (otherwise I would have just reinstalled everything). Due to missing release files I couldnt add the repo to either Kubuntu or Debian Live USB, but with the help of an Boot-Repair Live USB i was eventually able to boot to `initramfs` and had to decrypt the volume.

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt
# lvm vgchange -ay
exit
```

To be fair I am not sure, whether the commented command was necessary but I did it anyway. I had to make sure that `nvme0n1p3_crypt` was the same term as the first word in `/etc/crypttab` in front of the UUID. After the exit command my system would boot up (with possibly another password request). After successfull boot I had to run

```
update-initramfs -k all -c
```

and when that worked without complaining about missing (in my case) `nvme0n1p3_crypt` I was able to reboot as usual. Otherwise the term `nvme0n1p3_crypt` didnt match the term in `/etc/crypttab`.

However, I really dont understand much of what happend, but Im glad it worked out and this may possibly help others.